# Mysql query retrieving posts and filtering based on specific date intervals

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, select, filtering

Hi I am looking to integrate a dropdown select/option in a page storing a group of date intervals that would filter the mysql query by the corresponding selected option. Not sure if this is a duplicate, but couldn't find anything that was similar on here.

The table I am retrieving the "created date" from has a timestamp column.

Should this be a Mysql query, or handled with javascript? What would be the optimal solution?

Example:

```html
<h3>Posts Filter</h3>
<select>
  <option>All Time</option>
  <option>Past Day</option>
  <option>Past Week</option>
  <option>Past Month</option>
  <option>Past Year</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>
<hr>

<div style="width:45%;height:200px;float:left;border:1px solid #ddd;padding:10px;margin:2.5%;box-sizing:border-box;">
  <h2>Post Header</h2>
  <em>Created On: February 21 2017</em>
  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet short ribs kevin ribeye meatball filet mignon swine pork loin spare ribs, pork belly cow tenderloin venison...</p>
</div>

<div style="width:45%;height:200px;float:left;border:1px solid #ddd;padding:10px;margin:2.5%;box-sizing:border-box;">
  <h2>Post Header</h2>
  <em>Created On: February 18 2017</em>
  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet short ribs kevin ribeye meatball filet mignon swine pork loin spare ribs, pork belly cow tenderloin venison...</p>
</div>

<div style="width:45%;height:200px;float:left;border:1px solid #ddd;padding:10px;margin:2.5%;box-sizing:border-box;">
  <h2>Post Header</h2>
  <em>Created On: January 26 2016</em>
  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet short ribs kevin ribeye meatball filet mignon swine pork loin spare ribs, pork belly cow tenderloin venison...</p>
</div>

<div style="width:45%;height:200px;float:left;border:1px solid #ddd;padding:10px;margin:2.5%;box-sizing:border-box;">
  <h2>Post Header</h2>
  <em>Created On: March 15 2016</em>
  <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet short ribs kevin ribeye meatball filet mignon swine pork loin spare ribs, pork belly cow tenderloin venison...</p>
</div>
```

Thank you for any input!

Serge

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: it depends on the use case. You have to be aware of the trade-offs you're making:

1. **Implementing it in JavaScript** means that you will retrieve the entire MySQL table in one go, and perform filtering in the browser.

   - Query execution speed will be fast since no conditions need to be evaluated by the database
   - You will only need one round-trip to the database
   - The amount of data that needs to be sent over the wire will potentially be large
   - The amount of data that needs to be held in memory by the browser will potentially be large, so data transfer will be slower
   - Execution in the browser will potentially be slow if a large volume of data needs to be filtered
2. **Implementing it in a MySQL query** means that you will retrieve only that part of the table that matches your conditions and will not have to perform filtering in the browser.

   - Query execution speed will be slower since the database has to evaluate the conditions
   - You will potentially need multiple round-trips to the database
   - The amount of data that needs to be sent over the wire will be smaller, so data transfer will be faster
   - The amount of data that needs to be held in memory by the browser will be smaller
   - Execution in the browser will be fast since no filtering logic needs to be applied

As you can tell from the listings above, the size of the table plays a crucial factor. If the table is small, I would opt for the JavaScript approach. If the table is large (or will potentially grow large), I would opt for the query approach.

Comment: Robby, maybe I jumped the gun a little bit. All the records would be displayed on the page, but to make it easier for the person viewing the page, I would like to implement the filtering system. So regardless, i am still making the trip to the db to retrieve all the records, just need a way for the viewer to filter the content rendered on the page. From what I read from your post, then there's no need to make another (or several) additional trips to the db.

Comment: @Sergio That's correct. Go with a JavaScript solution in that case.

Comment: Thank you Robby. How can I utilize the timestamp in db to output into a div the conversion of the actual time stamp (ie: 2017-02-18 03:21:10) into a number representing the days ago (ie: 4 days ago)? Is there such calculation that can be performed in the query?

Comment: Think I have figured it out... by running this query - 
SELECT timestampdiff(DAY, now(), dateCreated) as days FROM posts

Answer (score 0):

Yes um handle by ajax...

```
<select id="select">
  <option value="all">All Time</option>
  <option value="day">Past Day</option>
  <option value="weel">Past Week</option>
  <option value="month">Past Month</option>
  <option value="year">Past Year</option>
</select>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#select").change(function() {


    $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "getSql",
                data:  { $(this).val() },
                success: function($response) {
                        response = $.parseJSON(reponse);
                        $.each(response, function(k, v) {
                            // key and value
                            $("YOUDIV").append(VALUE)
                        }); 



                }
            }); 

})


})

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Rafael. Since all the "posts/content" is already being pulled from the db and displayed on the page, is there a need to make another query to the db? And how would I utilize the timestamp for the posts to filter the posts to only the show posts within the date interval selected by the viewer?

Comment: Yes, ajax you make a query every time you change or select and populate your html but no page reload